# Raspberry Pi Python

Tags: python, adafruit

I know these questions are everywhere. However, I've tried this on several different `pi`'s and just **cannot** wrap my head around what I'm doing wrong.

Before I continue, yes, I have ran [the tutorial](http://learn.adafruit.com/character-lcd-with-raspberry-pi-or-beaglebone-black/usage).

And then I ran into the issue where it will not pick up `Adafruit_CharLCD` as a module, so I followed the advice I found on the internet and moved the `Adafruit_CharLCD.py` file to the same folder as my python projects. I also attempted just putting my python file in the `Adafruit_CharLCD` folder, but it caused so many more problems, so it seems it is not recommended.

My code is as follows. Very simple, I'm just trying to get this thing to run

```
#!/usr/bin/python python3
import time

import Adafruit_CharLCD as LCD

lcd = LCD.Adafruit_CharLCDPlate()
```

This returns the error

> ImportError: No module named 'Adafruit_GPIO'

so I followed the tutorial listed directly on Adafruit_GPIO
here: [adafruit/Adafruit_Python_GPIO](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_GPIO)

and now I am stumped. please let me know any advice you have. I have tried formatting and starting clean on 4 different `raspberry pis a b2`, `b2+`, and two `raspberry pi 3`'s. Please, any new information would be very helpful.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that the exact product I have  is "Adafruit Blue&White 16x2 LCD+Keypad Kit for Raspberry Pi"

Comment: I would very much like to get this solved by months end, if you have any ideas that you do no feel comfortable sharing here please PM me. if you would like to replicate it I am using jessie with pixel, although I've tried using lite. thank you for everything! keep smiling

Comment: Rather than just moving `Adafruit_CharLCD.py` to your project, move all the files in that folder over. They probably all depend on each other.

Comment: Thank you very much! every attempt before this I've tried cutting and pasting from the GUI, this time I did the very same through the terminal and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

It seem be not installed `Adafruit_Python_CharLCD` try this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-smbus python-pip
```

As you have `raspberry 3` install this:

```
sudo pip install RPi.GPIO
```